# Is there a way to get transactions for all container accounts belongs to a specific site aggregated using Yodle APIs?

Tags: yodlee

Is there a way to get transactions for all container accounts that belong to a specific site aggregated using Yodle APIs?

For example, the American Express Cards (siteId: 12) have bank, credits, loans and etc enabled containers.
So, can we get the transactions for all enabled container accounts for a single site?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to ask this- "Is there a way to get transactions for all the accounts(all containers) belongs to a particular site?" Then.

Yodlee provides two ways to get the transactions.

1. Getting transactions for a specific account i.e., you need to provide itemAccountId for each account to get the transactions for the specific account using executeUserSearchRequest API.
2. Getting transactions for all the accounts i.e., you need not to provide itemAccountId for any of the particular account while provide rest of the input parameters to get transactions using executeUserSearchRequest but this will return you transactions for all the accounts. Using your example, it will give you transactions for all the container present under SiteID-12 as well as other sites added by the consumer. Though you can use the second approach to get the transactions for all accounts and then filter it out for all containers belongs to a specific site. You can use the sumInfoId(ContentServiceID) present in the response for each transaction.